# saving files to a specific folder in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Pls am working  on  a windows application Destop messenger  I want to save  file to folders like music images e.t.c I don't know how to go about it please any help will be   appreciated

Comment: If you need to save to a 'specific folder' or to 'another folder' why do you need a dialog?  The question is very unclear.  See ]Ask]

Comment: I have rephrased the question

Comment: `Environment.GetFolderPath()`

Comment: What is the code that receives these files and how are they stored before you save them?

Answer (score 0):

IN Visual Studio 2013 you can use  FolderBrowserDialog and DialogResult

```
MessageBox.Show("Select your path", "Attention")

Dim select As New FolderBrowserDialog()

Dim resultSel As DialogResult = select.ShowDialog()

If Not select.SelectedPath.Equals(String.Empty) Then

    ' Save your File
End If
```

Comment: Please how am I to save it pls @  rdn87

Comment: @Ebruski You need to post you code that shows how you receive the files and how you store them before they are saved. Without this, it isn't possible to even start providing a full answer. If you haven't written that code then we really cant help.